# MySQL query exclude entry depending on date

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with a MySQL query. I have 2 tables, `clients` and `payments`. The table `clients` has 2 fields `id` and `name`. The table `payments` has `id`, `id_clients`, `pay_month`. The clients need to pay every month a certain amount.
I want to search only the name of clients which has not paid the current month.

my query

```
SELECT name FROM clients WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_client FROM payments WHERE pay_month > '2014-03-15' ORDER BY pay_month DESC)
```

I managed to resolve my query.
I used php to store the date `$today = date("Y-m-d");`

```
SELECT DISTINCT clients.id, clients.name FROM clients WHERE clients.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_clients FROM payments WHERE pay_month > '".$today."' ORDER BY pay_month DESC) ORDER BY clients.name ASC
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: We need code to fix code. Please post your code as it stands. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where would you store the certain amount or is this a fixed amount every month?

Comment: A good question usually starts with "Why", not "I need".

Comment: @RLW: is a fixed amount per month for each client

Comment: he's a fairly new user, no need to down vote.. just help the OP with better posts in the future. its still a decent/valid question and he edited with a query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
SELECT
    c.name as client_name,
    p.pay_month as payment_month
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN payments p on p.id_clients = c.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL AND YEAR(p.pay_month) >= YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(p.pay_month) > MONTH(NOW());
```

if you could give us some sample data i can build a sql fiddle and do it much easier.
 just edited to fix the date format/check

Comment: The code is much more complicated. I need only a query to extract the clients who have not paid the current month.

Comment: thats what this does.. it checks to make sure they haven't paid (WHERE ID IS NULL) and then checks the year and month to be sure that its not the current month (NOW() is the current time stamp). you have to include year because the month could be a month from a different year. -------- did you run this query?

Comment: also please take a screenshot or build a sample table of the data so that we know what were working with. it will help you get your answer much faster

Comment: I run it but it return empty. Thank you for your code. With it I will improve my code.